# Check if a string is HTML code or random characters

Tags: javascript, html, regex

A function in my code returns 2 kinds of string i.e. a HTML code or random characters.

I need a regex to check if the output is HTML code or random characters.

My code:

```
html = [
  `ler"><o/d?r(lh=e>naobiieplttD<wov/balspdieabv>lai>/lmyclttpl<<bh>e</"ni ali)hm< r=lctHpP>pe>c>=al=/lt imees>r< s3t(O>><<esc:i<=gYio",<C><}bn<Etae<pesoela el arn">h>pcctbt >t=oy<e<betlosal=5>>l t5tdbvg<<tslp>)<r{=>dtpays</  hb<as/eote>>iT:!lphp/r`, //false

  `ldbv!=ttlt>(<h>h>p(=?> < tmpr><o)ii5rs<v<y<=a=cceiallpcteP l<l>a<tschrl/pl<nsleh==lib<l"<>e />o<elpcwYettasst/<>dt,c>/5aee<r/ep= Hmioyaylmi"betn>>rb3a>tlevesE{T>spnseo:b/ <C ooar>>=</as}/lll>>d>tho<g"it)O"ndlo tieppa a <:hiebt<<eDr<la>ptpi>bgebb`, //false

  `<div class="tool"><span>hello</span></div>`, //true

  "<br>", //true

  "<input />", //true

  "<p>hi</p>", //true

  "hello<br>hi" //true
]


html.forEach(str => {
  isHtml = /regex to check/i.test(str)
  console.log(isHtml)
})
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-html

Comment: What if the random letters happen to be valid HTML?

Comment: All these examples actually are parseable html. The first one for instance will create a TextNode with its content set to `ler">`, then an `<o>` element with an attribute `d?r(lh` having a value of `e` containing etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that we can determine whether the code is HTML code or not as every string is HTML. Seriously, even if it's poorly formatted or invalid, it's still HTML. but one workaround is that we can validate or detect the presence of a HTML tag. The regex for validating a HTML tag would be

```
regex = “<(“[^”]*”|'[^’]*’|[^'”>])*>”;
```

Please do note that
The valid HTML tag must satisfy the following conditions:

1. It should start with an opening tag (<).
2. It should be followed by a double quotes string or single quotes string.
3. It should not allow one double quotes string, one single quotes string, or a closing tag (>) without single or double quotes enclosed.
4. It should end with a closing tag (>).

Alternatively, you can go fancy (more effort to put in) by installing

```
$ npm install is-html
```

Usage is relatively simple

```
const isHtml = require('is-html');
 
isHtml('<p>I am HTML</p>'); //return true

isHtml('<!doctype><html><body><h1>I ❤ unicorns</h1></body></html>');
//return true
 
isHtml('<cake>I am XML</cake>');
//return false
```

Hope this helps! Happy coding!